# NSIS message box custom buttons

Tags: button, nsis

I know this has been asked before and found several posts where they say no, but the most recent post I seen was from 2014, so I figure I would check to see if there is any new functionality I am missing.

Is there a way to change the message box buttons to custom text?  So instead of `YesNoCancel` I can use `UninstallReinstallCancel`.

There are several message boxes I need to have this ability for.

If the option is write some custom plugin, could someone do this for me it would be over my head?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSIS just uses the [MessageBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx) Windows function and that does not allow you to set the button text.

The best option would be a custom plug-in but I doubt anyone is willing to write one for you just because you ask nicely. You could ask on the NSIS forum if anyone is willing to do it for a small fee perhaps.

As a workaround you can use the [DlgHost plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/DlgHost_plug-in) on built-in pages to create a nested dialog with your own custom design:

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh
!include DlgHost.nsh

Page InstFiles

Function CloseDlgHostDialog
Pop $0
DlgHost::Close
FunctionEnd

Function DoSomethingElse
Pop $0
MessageBox mb_ok "Hello"
FunctionEnd

Function MyDlgBoxCallback
${Select} $0
${Case} ${DLGHOST_DLGBOXMSG_INITDLG}
    nsDialogs::Create 1018
    Pop $1
    DlgHost::SetClient $1

    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 25% 20% 45% 15u "Hello from nsDialogs..."
    Pop $1
    ${NSD_CreateButton} 10u 60% 50u 15u "&Close"
    Pop $1
    ${NSD_OnClick} $1 CloseDlgHostDialog

    ${NSD_CreateButton} 70u 60% 80u 15u "&Do something else"
    Pop $1
    ${NSD_OnClick} $1 DoSomethingElse

${Case} ${DLGHOST_DLGBOXMSG_SHOWDLG}
    nsDialogs::Show
${EndSelect}
FunctionEnd

Function ShowNSDChildDlg
GetFunctionAddress $0 MyDlgBoxCallback
DlgHost::DlgBox "* $0 p 200u 120u Test Dialog"
FunctionEnd

Section
Call ShowNSDChildDlg
SectionEnd
```